# Как передать в laravel route() параметр от vue

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

Я создал компонент vue вот так:

```js
    Vue.component("modal", {
        props: ["description", "header", "closeFunction", "detailLink"],
        template: "<transition name='bounce'>" +
            "<div class='wrapper' @click='closeFunction'>" +
            "<div class='container'>" +
            "<div class='close_button' @click='closeFunction'></div>" +
            "<h3>{{ header }}</h3>" +
            "<div class='content'>{{ description | truncate(300) }}</div>" +
            "<a v-bind:href='detailLink' class='custom-btn btn-1'>Подробнее</a>" +
            "</div></div>" +
            "</transition>"
    });
```

и пытаюсь использовать его на странице:

```html
        <modal v-show="show"
               v-bind:header="header"
               v-bind:description="description"
               v-bind:close-function="closeModal"
               v-bind:detail-link="{{ route("detail-page", id) }}"> // ошибка

        </modal>
```

Как видно из вызова компонента я пытаюсь использовать функцию `route()` с `Laravel` и передать в него вторым аргументом свойство `id` которое в `$data.id` (`data: { id: ... }`), для того чтобы в `web.php` использовать `Route::get("/detail/{id}"...)`. Из за этого `laravel` естественно выдает ошибку `"id" is not defined`. В документации я ничего не нашел.

**Как сделать чтобы свойство объекта vue передавалось в функцию route() laravel**? 
UPD: vue.js объект

```js
    let modal = new Vue({
        el: "#modal",
        data: {
            header: '',
            description: '',
            id: 0, // вот это свойство нужно использовать как второй аргумент route()
            show: false
        },
        methods: {
            closeModal() {
                this.show = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

значения свойств `header`, `description`, `id`, `show` изменяются вызовом функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, думаю, нужно прояснить один важный момент. Шаблонизатор (blade) обрабатывается на стороне php сервера, а vue(js) на стороне клиента. Поэтому в функцию `route` не выйдет передать параметр из vue.

Первое решение, которое пришло в голову такое:
В `route` передаем параметр, который потом заменим на нужный id во vue-компоненте.

```
<modal v-show="show"
    v-bind:header="header"
    v-bind:description="description"
    v-bind:close-function="closeModal"
    detail-link="{{ route('detail-page', 'xxx') }}"></modal>
```

Потом в компоненте создаем метод или вычисляемое свойство, где будем менять ‘ххх’ на нужный id. Там нужно будет вернуть что-то вроде

```
getDetailLinkWithId(){
    return this.detailLink.replace('xxx', this.id);
},
```

Вместо ххх можете поставить свою подстроку. Минусов у этого метода много, но он прост.

И еще, раз уж Вы передаете строку, то v-bind, думаю, ненужен.

Answer (score 1):

Если вызывается в blade шаблоне, то скорее всего проблема в синтаксисе, попробуйте так:

```
<modal v-show="show"
  v-bind:header="header"
  v-bind:description="description"
  v-bind:close-function="closeModal"
  v-bind:detail-link="{{ route('detail-page', $id) }}">
</modal>
```

Comment: undefined variable

Comment: может искать другой подход?

Comment: к тому же, `id` это ведь свойство объекта vue

Comment: обновил вопрос. посмотрите

Comment: Так а чем этот объект вызывается? Нужно в этот файл и прокидывать $id